# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to path is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, plesk, application-pool, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Good afternoon,
I have recently purchased a server with Plesk 12 as the Control Panel.
I don't have much experience using Plesk.

For testing purposes, I created a simple ASP.NET project which tries to read/write from a txt, as shown below:

```
String logPath = @"C:\inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs\log_application_error.txt";
StreamWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(logPath, true);
```

When the StreamWriter instance is created, I get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs\log_application_error.txt' is denied.
```

I tried granting read/write permissions to the txt file, and even granted Full Control to "Everyone", but the result was the same.

Plesk seems to hide everything so that it is handled through the Control Panel. I don't see any Applications Pools on the IIS so I am not even sure what is the identity it is running under.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set "Additonal write/modify permissions" at "Hosting settings" of your domain:

[image: Plesk write permissions]

Comment: BTW, do you know if there's any way to set the Application Pool to recycle at a specific time? This is easily done through the Recycling Settings on the IIS, but haven't seen this option on Plesk

Comment: Well, all IIS Pool recycle settings can be found here https://<your plesk host>:8443/smb/iis-app-pool/settings But there is no option to set specific time, only by time interval which has default 1740 minutes (29 hours).

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it with following commands:

cacls C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL /E /R psacln /T /C

cacls C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL /E /R psaadm /T /C

Comment: Thanks Igor for the prompt reply. I don't see how granting permissions to the GAC can solve this issue. Would you mind providing more information? Thank you